# Image in WebView not loaded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

For some reason the image in my WebView is not loaded. I can't figure out why even after trying multiple solution here. Please help me to resolve this issue.

My application WebView

[image]

My AVD browser view

[image]

link to the page is [here](https://www.malaysiakini.com/news/350548)

My `WebViewActivity` class

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

    final WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //TextView contentView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contentView);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String address = intent.getStringExtra("URL");


    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }
    });


    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(address);


    //textToSpeech.speak("TALK", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [mixed content](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorWebView) issue because you are calling `http` protocol while using `https` protocol in your Webview.

Change mixed content mode with [`setMixedContentMode(int mode)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMixedContentMode(int)) :

```
webview.getSettings().
    setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);
```

From [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE) for `MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE` :

> Used with setMixedContentMode(int) In this mode, the WebView will attempt to be compatible with the approach of a modern web browser with regard to mixed content. Some insecure content may be allowed to be loaded by a secure origin and other types of content will be blocked. The types of content are allowed or blocked may change release to release and are not explicitly defined. This mode is intended to be used by apps that are not in control of the content that they render but desire to operate in a reasonably secure environment. For highest security, apps are recommended to use MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW.